# How to change the default MVC T4 Template location?

Tags: model-view-controller, t4

I know the templates are in : [Visual Studio Install Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates[CSharp | VisualBasic]\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates\

And I know I can just simply copy the CodeTemplates folder into the root of the project to override the plates.

I would like to know if it is possible to simply change the default template directory
eg change it to: [shared drive]\Visual Studio templates\CodeTemplates

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx